# C++ variable length array on the stack

Tags: c++, arrays

I've just encountered code in the project [dcraw](http://www.cybercom.net/~dcoffin/dcraw/) that's causing the Visual Studio 2012 compiler to fail. It's of the following form:

```
void CLASS cubic_spline (const int *x_, const int *y_, const int len)
{
  float A[2*len][2*len], b[2*len], c[2*len], d[2*len];
  ...
```

The problem is the creation of these variable length arrays on the stack. I've never really seen code like this -- is it possible to compile this in the Visual Studio compiler?

Comment: dcdraw is written in c, not c++. c and c++ are two different languages with a similar syntax.

Comment: C++ does not support [Variable Length Arrays](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array) except as compiler extensions (a la gcc).

Comment: I didn't realize variable length arrays were valid C and not C++. My mistake on mis-tagging the question as C++: it's not normally that important to distinguish between the languages, but in this case it appears to be!

Comment: @aardvarkk: It is always important to distinguish between C and C++. Compiler errors are just the tip of the iceberg.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit It generates a compiler error.

Comment: @aardvarkk Do I have to guess what that error is? Is this some kind of puzzle?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit The error message itself is not overly relevant. The problem is trying to compile code containing VLAs in Visual Studio. I mention that in the question. Why does it help for me to tell you the output is: `error C2057: expected constant expression`?

Comment: The message is always relevant and I don't understand why you'd go out of your way to hide it from the authorities. You're the one with the question so you are not qualified to decide that some details don't help.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit You seem to be the only one who's having trouble on this one... I didn't go out of my way to hide it. I just posted it above. I try to keep my questions as concise as possible. I know why the error is generated, as does everybody else who answered. Please tell me what additional information you can offer now that you have seen the error message that you couldn't have offered before.

Comment: @aardvarkk It's a general principle for the general case. That it's possible to guess _this time_ doesn't mean it's appropriate to make us do so. Write terse, _complete_ problem descriptions on this website please, rather than being deliberately obtuse.

Answer (score 2):

There are working compiler extensions (such as [Clang's one](http://clang.llvm.org/compatibility.html) and [GCC's one](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.3.0/gcc/Variable-Length.html)) that allow this, but it's not standard, yet.

In C++11 you can also use [`constexpr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constexpr) if the numeric value is constant. And finally [a proposal](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/sc22/WG21/docs/papers/2013/n3662.html) has been submitted to standardize it.

If `x_` and `y_` are meant to be arrays, you can just use [`std::array`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) as follows:

```
template<std::size_t size>
void CLASS cubic_spline (std::array<int, size> const& x, std::array<int, size> const& y)
{
    using float_array = std::array<float, 2 * size>;
    std::array<float_array, 2 * size> A;
    float_array b, c, d;
    // ...
}
```

This way you could ensure that the passed arrays dimensions are equal, at compile time.

Otherwise you can clean that up with [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector):

```
void CLASS cubic_spline (std::vector<int> const& x, std::vector<int> const& y)
{
    std::vector<std::vector<float>> A(2 * x.size());
    std::vector<float> b, c, d;
    // ...
}
```

Comment: How would this code look were it to take advantage of the constexpr syntax?

Comment: @aardvarkk: `constexpr` would only work for compile-time computations, would it be alright with you ?

Comment: @aardvarkk, it's hard to say, because `constexpr` can't just be blindly used to replace `const`. For example you can't put `constexpr` as a function argument. What are `x_` and `y_` in your example?

Comment: The function is called twice in the code, once as `cubic_spline(cx, cf, 9);` and once as `cubic_spline(cx, cf, 18);`. In the first example, `cx` and `cy` are `int[9]` and in the second example they're `int[18]`.

Comment: This is a question about C and variable length arrays are a standard core C99 feature. No need for extensions.

Comment: @Danvil, erm, the question was tagged C++ and referred to C++ originally.

Comment: OP tagged it as C. You changed it to C++. That does not count ;) But anyway, dcraw is a C program.

Comment: @Danvil, I simply rolled it back. See the [revision history](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/23569150/1).

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned, VLA (Variable-Length Arrays) are a C feature, and more to the point a C99 feature which Visual Studio does not support. On Linux, Clang and Gcc both support C99 (and C11 I believe) and allow this syntax in C++ as an extension.

In C++, you can easily transform the code by switching to `std::vector<float>` for all simple arrays. Only `A` will require a bit more work:

- you can either use a `std::vector< std::vector<float> >`, but then you lose contiguity and locality
- or you can use a flattened version `std::vector<float> A(2*len*2*len);` but then you will lose access by `A[i][j]` which will have to be transformed into `A[i*2*len + j]` instead

In any case, you will need to update this code to make it work on Visual Studio.

**EDIT**: per your comment:

> The function is called twice in the code, once as `cubic_spline(cx, cf, 9);` and once as `cubic_spline(cx, cf, 18);`. In the first example, `cx` and `cy` are `int[9]` and in the second example they're `int[18]`.

In this case you can actually make the function a template:

```
template <size_t len>
void CLASS cubic_spline(int const (&x)[len], int const (&y)[len]) {
    float A[2*len][2*len], b[2*len], c[2*len], d[2*len];
}
```

Note that I removed the last parameter, because it is no longer necessary. The type of `x` and `y` is `int const (&)[len]` which is a reference to an array of `int const` of length `len`.

Comment: Very helpful post, thanks. I knew VS didn't support C99, so it answers the question quite directly to know that not only are VLAs a C feature, but specifically a C99 feature.

Comment: @aardvarkk: actually, if the dimensions are known at compile time, you can much more easily deal with the issue by just transforming the signature of `cubic_spline` to make it Standard C++. I've edited my answer to show off the power of references to array in function template :)

Answer (score 1):

This is a GCC-specific compiler extension, see [Arrays of Variable Length](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.3.0/gcc/Variable-Length.html). I am not aware of any compiler options to make them work out of the box in VC. If this is a very isolated problem, try preprocessor `#ifdef`s to serve different code to VC.

Comment: Not true. VLA's are a C99 standard feature (and this question is tagged as C by OP).

Comment: @Danvil: I see it tagged as C++.

Comment: There is some kind of continuous editing... Anyway, dcraw is a C program.

Comment: I guess it should finally be re-tagged as C :)

Comment: It's my mistake -- I wrongly tagged it as C++ without realizing `dcraw` was in fact written in C. This appears to be one of the few things that is genuinely different between C and C++.